# How to prevent a route conflict in the managed switch, when a Mesh router fallbacks to the Wi-Fi mode?

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I have got a very specific network. I own the good performance routers, but they're terribly limited in configuration options, so I mostly have to use workarounds to get them working as intended.

The network looks like this:

[image]

My Internet connection uses a different fiber provider, and a different ISP. The fiber provider gives an ONT device with 1 Ethernet output. This could only be connected through the ISP router, but I used some tricks with the TL-SG108E switch, and inserted a custom MAC address of the WAN port, so the connection successes.

In my 1Gb/s TL-SG108E switch, I set VLAN 40 for ports 1-2, where port 1 is tagged, and port 2 is untagged. Port 1 has ethernet connection with fiber provider's ONT device, and port 2 goes to the Main Router (Xiaomi AX6000) WAN port, which connects using "DHCP" connection settings. The Local DHCP server is also on the AX6000 router.

Using the 2.5Gb port, I connect to the unmanaged 5-ports 2.5Gb switch, so I can get over ~1.5Gb/s from my NAS devices over Wi-Fi and from my desktop PC with 2.5Gb port.

This 2.5Gb switch also connects to the TL-SG108E switch on port 8, which is in the untagged VLAN (100) network of ports 3-8.

Then, one of these ports (3 to 7) connects by the Ethernet cable to the mesh router (Xiaomi AX3600) in another room.

**This solution (visible in my picture) works perfectly fine, until the Mesh router randomly establishes the Wi-Fi connection between the Mesh and the Main router**. This can be caused either by one of routers reboot, one of Switches reboot, or randomly due to some periodical check. Unfortunately, I'm unable to configure it on any of the routers. It's just done automatically :/

When this happens, my unmanaged 2.5Gb switch gets an error (RED led blinking), and I have to fix it by disconnecting the Mesh Ethernet manually (or shutting down the port in the managed switch). This is because of a conflict. When a Mesh router gets connected with the Main router over Wi-Fi, the 2.5Gb Switch probably sees the same address on both ends (AX6000 router and TL-SG108E switch).

**Why not use the LAN port in the AX6000 router?**

[The AX6000 router](https://www.androidpimp.com/wireless-routers/xiaomi-mi-aiot-ax6000-review/) has the maximum throughput of devices connected to the 1Gb ports (including WAN) of 1Gb. This means, that that all 3 LAN ports (one of them can be used as WAN) can get maximum 1Gb/s. In my case it causes a problem with lower Internet speeds on both routers (AX6000 and AX3600). Instead of ~950Mb/s download speed, I "only" get ~700Mb/s download speed. These speeds are not always the same, but the conclusion is clear: the shared speed is not enough for me to be satisfied with my new Internet connection :(

**What help do I need?**

I would like to know, if there's some other workaround / TL-SG108E switch configuration that could help me avoid this conflict? I'm not an expert when it comes to the network configuration, so I possibly skipped some possibilities. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't know your Hardware, but I'd try to connect the mesh directly to the 2.5gb switch. And if needed, connect the 1gb switch to the mesh (or to the main router).

Comment: @1NN It has the same effect, unfortunately. Meshes will still connect each other by Wi-Fi from time to time, and cause the Switch to automatically detect the conflict and alert it with the red LED.

Comment: @BlindSpots It doesn't really matter if it's connected to the LAN or WAN port on this router. It automatically detects the main mesh and establishes a wired connection. The mesh mode works flawlessly fine (1Gb/s wired connection between routers, devices switching without disconnecting / interrupting transfers). The only issue is, that these routers sometimes are also establishing a Wi-Fi connection with each other, and cause switches to "freeze" (after detecting the conflict).
I don't want it to work in the Repeater Mode, as Mesh gives huge benefits.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Layer 2 switching loop (Ethernet MAC based) is created when the extra WiFi connection is made. That leads to a broadcast storm of packets being passed around the loop which leads to the error. See [this guide](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-study-guide/layer-2-switching-loops-in-network-explained.html) for more background info.

Typically you want to turn on a technology called [Spanning Tree Protocol (STP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) or its successor [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol#Rapid_Spanning_Tree_Protocol) which would identify loops and disable them.

A challenge may be the un-managed switch - it may or may not support STP, and some do and do not advertise the fact.

I hope this helps!